# How to insert a numpy 2d array into a single pyspark dataframe cell

Tags: python, numpy, pyspark

I'm trying to insert the entirety of a numpy 2d array into a single pyspark row... does anyone know how to achieve this?

Ultimately I would like to be able to achieve the below.. where my numpy array is in a single row

[image]

I have tried to use higher order function to do this, but haven't been able to get this working so far. Does anyone have any advice?

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import numpy as np

df = spark.createDataFrame(np.array([[0.        , 0.67235401, 0.35767577],
       [0.67235401, 0.        , 0.2981656 ],
       [0.35767577, 0.2981656 , 0.        ]]))

expr = "TRANSFORM(arrays_zip(*), x -> struct(*))"
df = sms.withColumn('array', f.expr(expr))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a `numpy.array`, it can converted into PySpark Dataframe after converting array into a python list.

## Working Example

```py
import numpy as np

np_array = np.array([[0.        , 0.67235401, 0.35767577],
       [0.67235401, 0.        , 0.2981656 ],
       [0.35767577, 0.2981656 , 0.        ]])

df = spark.createDataFrame([(np_array.tolist(), )], ("array", ))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

### Output

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|array                                                                                      |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[[0.0, 0.67235401, 0.35767577], [0.67235401, 0.0, 0.2981656], [0.35767577, 0.2981656, 0.0]]|
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```